# Debian 10.5 live usb boots to grub

Tags: linux, boot, grub

After downloading Debain amd64 iso for installing a new system and writing it to a usb stick with `dd if=iso of=/dev/sdX` like normal and going through the paces to boot from the usb, I boot to debian but to a grub command prompt instead of launching the installer.  I created a virtual machine with the same iso and installed debian perfectly from it.

I"m missing something, probably about UEFI from what i've found so far.  I can follow the exact same process with an ubuntu iso and install ubuntu on the same machine. Any tips?

Answer (score 1):

figured it out - digging through the bios settings i was able to disable UEFI and boot with legacy mode off the USB